# date range based on year and quarter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have an attribute `quarter`, which I save in a string form - `"2015-1"`, meaning year 2015 and first quarter of the year.

How can I get the range of all dates within this `quarter`?

I need it for inclusion validation:

```
validates :date,
    presence: true,
    inclusion: { in: something_that_returns_the_range_from_quarter_attr }
```

Comment: I'm little confused. Do you want validate `quarter` attr?

Comment: I don't. I need to validate attribute called `date`. And this date should be included into a range of values, which are got (somehow) from `quarter` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
#i would do the validation like so
validates :date_in_quarter

def date_in_quarter
  if self.date.blank? || !self.quarter_date_range.include?(self.date)
    self.errors.add(:date, "is blank or not in allowed range")
  end
end 

#the validation uses this method which gets date range from quarter attribute
def quarter_date_range
  year, quarter = self.quarter.split("-").collect(&:to_i)
  start_month = ((3 * quarter) - 2)
  start_date = Date.parse("#{year}-#{start_month}-01")
  end_date = start_date + 3.months - 1.day
  start_date..end_date
end
```

Comment: Just fixed a missing open bracket in the `quarter_date_range` method. :)